# Manage your terminals

Tags: command-line

I work with terminals all the time, and most of the windows opened are teminals. I would like to get them somehow organized, for example in tabs. But the problem is I open them from nautilus (Open in Remote Terminal https://github.com/umpirsky/nautilus-scripts/blob/master/Open%20in%20Remote%20Terminal) so it opens always a new window.

Is there any tool that can keep then on one terminal window in separate tabs? I saw terminator, but that works separated from native ubuntu terminal app.

Comment: ctrl+shift+t might help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have terminal window "A" open and terminal window "B" open.
You can select window "A", then open another tab in that window with Ctrl + Shift + T.
After that you can click and drag Tab "A" to "B" leaving a window with the last created tab alone and a new window with your two old windows "A" and "B" as tabs.

After this you can right click on the tabs to give them labels.
I can do this with the gnome-terminal, a.k.a. the standard terminal.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then you can change the default switch to next tab to a more practical key.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Only strange thing is strange shortcuts in terminal. Change tab is Ctrl+Page Down. Very strange choice, Ctrl+Tab would be more appropriate.

Comment: Edit -> keyboard shortcuts -> Tabs. Swap it to what fits you.

Comment: Thanks, great tip. For some reason it does not accept Ctrl+Tab :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for Compiz that enables you to group and tab different windows of any kind. It's not entirely stable though. :)

The plugin is called Group and Tab and it's available in the compiz-plugins-extra package.